# Laravel ohmybrew/laravel-shopify Client error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shopify-app

I am using laravel ohmybrew/laravel-shopify for creating a shopify app 
After installed the package i followed ohmybrew Documentation and did all the steps but in https://domainname/authenticate
i got this error

```
Client error: `POST https://pad- 
ux.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json` resulted in a `422 
Unprocessable Entity` response: {"errors":{"topic":["Invalid 
topic specified. Topics allowed: app\/uninstalled, 
collections\/create, collections\/delete (truncated...)
```

I am very much thankful if you give me some solution.

Comment: Try @ https://github.com/ohmybrew/laravel-shopify/issues/26

Comment: well thank you so much and it works!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked :) Keep rocking!